# Rally sdk 2 utility to create link to details page/edit popup

Tags: javascript, rally

Is there an equivalent in SDK 2 to the SDK 1 navigation utilities?  I'd like to create a link in a grid to a test case's details page.  I can handcraft it with a renderer, but is there a utility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now there is not.  We hope to create a standard way of doing this by the time the SDK 2.0 goes GA.

Comment: huh. so I thought I could hand-roll it, but this link pops up a blank rally screen (colors are there, but no links!) when I put it into an a href with a target of _blank:  https://audemo.rallydev.com/slm/detail/tc/2056272

Comment: But only if the link is in an SDK2 grid.  When it's in plain html, it works fine.  I'll open a new question.